# Java annotations not being found in JAR file using org.reflections

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I'm using the org.reflections library to detect some classes that are annotated in my project. When I run the project from eclipse, the annotated classes are found.

However, when the project is packaged into a JAR file and run, no annotated classes are found.

Here is some example code:

```
@TestAnnotation
public class App {
    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.package"); 
        Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(TestAnnotation.class); 

        for (Class c : annotated) { 
            System.out.println ("found annotated class " + c.getName()); 
        } 
    }
}
```

When I run this code in a JAR file there is no output. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: could you show us the code of your annotation?

Comment: I have the same issue when starting with Webstart.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.package");
```

There you try to explore annotated classes located in **package** package which is nested in **com** package. But `package` is Java keyword. So it can not be used as name of package. After I moved `App` and `TestAnnotation` just into **com** package everything works fine.

But it is possible that your case is really bad. May be some tool or some person created package that has **package** name (for example, used Cyrillic `а` instead of Latin `a`, both are looking same in editor, but they are totally different for Java). When letters are mixed everything looks fine but doesn't work. So try to create new valid root package and move your classes into it.